# invalidSearchFilter when searching my videos using YouTube api v3

Tags: google-api, youtube, youtube-api

I keep getting invalidSearchFilter error when using YouTube API v3. I have the following params:

```
part: snippet
q: testtag
forMine: true
type: video
```

I am using the API playground, and noticed that if I do an OAuth call, it will work, but with just the API key (Execute without OAuth), it fails. Same thing happens in my code. A basic list call works in both, so I am suspecting a bug in their API, or I'm missing something.

Can anyone else confirm this to see if I'm missing something?

It works if I leave off the forMine and type params, but then it searches globally, which is not what I want.

I have searched for this, and the only other references I've found have been related to not setting the type param, but I have it set.

I found this link which suggests a possible API bug: [youtube v3 api error when searching with forMine set to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33508077/youtube-v3-api-error-when-searching-with-formine-set-to-false)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation is your friend [Search: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#http-request)

> forMine   boolean 
> This parameter can only be used in a properly
>   **authorized request**. The forMine parameter restricts the search to only
>   retrieve videos owned by the authenticated user. If you set this
>   parameter to true, then the type parameter's value must also be set to
>   video.

So yes you are missing something the part where you can only use [forMime](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters) type parameter with authorized requests. Using an Api key is an unauthorized request you are accessing the public API.  How do you think it would be able to search videos that yours if you aren't authenticated? It doesn't know who you are.

Comment: Ah - thank you. I thought using the API key meant it would know who I am. But now I know better! :o)