# YouTube API - Count uploads within a time period

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I manage a YouTube CMS and am trying to count the number of uploads within a given month. A CMS can have multiple channels, I want the aggregate number of uploads.

From the documentation, I feel like this should work:

```
function videosList($service, $part, $params) {
    $params = array_filter($params);
    $response = $service->search->listSearch($part,$params);
    print_r($response);
}

videosList($youtube,"snippet",array(
    array('forContentOwner' => true),
    'type' => 'video',
    'maxResults' => 1,
    'onBehalfOfContentOwner' => $CMSID,
    'publishedBefore' => date("c",strtotime("first day of this month")),
    'publishedAfter' => date("c",strtotime("first day of last month"))            
));
```

But the result is listing all public videos within the timeframe, not just those videos from the channels that I manage within $CMSID.

For reference, the API documentation says:

> The forContentOwner parameter restricts the search to **only retrieve videos owned by the content owner** identified by the onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter. If forContentOwner is set to true, the request must also meet these requirements:
>   The onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter is required.
>   The user authorizing the request must be using an account linked to the specified content owner.
>   The type parameter value must be set to video.
>   None of the following other parameters can be set: videoDefinition, videoDimension, videoDuration, videoLicense, videoEmbeddable, videoSyndicated, videoType.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list), you will see that you have missing part where you can use the `forMine` parameter. As what was discussed in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299548/invalidsearchfilter-when-searching-my-videos-using-youtube-api-v3?lq=1).

> `forMine`
>   **boolean**
>
> This parameter can only be used in a properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication).
>   The **forMine** parameter restricts the search to only retrieve videos
>   owned by the authenticated user. If you set this parameter to **true**,
>   then the **type** parameter's value must also be set to **video**. In
>   addition, none of the following other parameters can be set in the
>   same request: **videoDefinition**, **videoDimension**, **videoDuration**,
>   **videoLicense**, **videoEmbeddable**, **videoSyndicated**, **videoType**.

When you check [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46932139/youtube-api-v3-search-publishedafter-invalidsearchfilter?rq=1), it was also cited here that,

> The problem is the conflicting search restrictions that you used. To
>   make your search work, leave the `forMine` parameter empty so it
>   doesn't conflict with your date filters and possibly the `q` parameter
>   as well.

Comment: The authenticated user is a YouTube partner with multiple CMSs. So I need to specify both the forContentOwner and onBehalfOfContentOwner parameters.